# Need basic understanding of python arguments in order to be able code system of ODE's solution

Tags: python

I am an old Fortran programmer and need to help a young person to numerically solve an ODE system using Heun's method.  He only knows Python so I have to learn the minimum python to get this done.

Here is what I came up with.  The test code is for a simple 2 degree of freedom system with exponential growth for each degree of freedom.

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 28, in <module>
    heun (imax, y, dt, t)
  File "program.py", line 7, in heun
    rhs(y, ydot)
NameError: global name 'ydot' is not defined
```

Here is the code:

```
# Test RHS of ODE system:
def rhs (y, ydot):
    ydot[0] = y[0]
    ydot[1] = y[1]
    return;

# Does one step of Heun's method:
def heun (imax, y, dt, t):
    rhs(y, ydot)
    for i in range(0, imax):
       y_tilde[i] = y[i] + dt * ydot[i]

    rhs(y_tilde, ydot_at_tilde)
    for i in range(0, imax):
       y[i] = y[i] + dt/2 * (ydot[i] + ydot_at_tilde[i])

    t = t + dt
    return;

# Initial condition
y = [0, 0]
t = 0

dt     = 0.01
nsteps = 100
imax   = 1

istep = 1
while istep <= nsteps:
    heun (imax, y, dt, t)
    print istep, y[0], y[1]
    istep = istep + 1
```

Question: Why does python think that the object ydot in routine heun is global?  Even if it were global, why can't I pass it as an argument?

Comment: what is ydot????

Comment: As it says: `NameError: global name 'ydot' is not defined`.

Comment: Your error is clear, you are passing a variable that has not been declared, what equation do you want to implement?

Comment: I think you want to use pointers, in python there is no such concept.

Comment: What do you want to return in `heun` function, `t` or some else

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
def heun(imax, y, dt, t):
    rhs(y, ydot)
```

You're calling your `rhs` function, with the input arguments `y` and `ydot`. But `ydot` doesn't exist inside the scope of your `heun` function. Only `imax`, `y`, `dt` and `t` do.

Similarly you never define the variables `ydot_tilde` or `ydot_at_tilde`

Also, you're going to need your functions to return some values.

Comment: In fortran I would declare (in subroutine heun) ydot as an array.  Fortran would would dynamically allocate storage for ydot and pass the address of ydot to subroutine rhs where ydot would be given its values.  At the exit of subroutine heun, ydot would be deallocated.

Comment: In Python variables only exist inside the scope of the function (unless it's a global variable). To exist in the scope they either need to be defined inside the function, or passed in as a argument.

Answer (score 1):

OK thank-you all.  Here is a code that works with comments to indicate what I learnt:

```
def rhs (y, ydot):
    ydot[0] = y[0]
    ydot[1] = y[1]
    return ydot;

def heun (ndof, dt, y, t):
    # These initializations of local arrays take the place of Fortran declarations:
    ydot          = [0] * (ndof)
    y_tilde       = [0] * (ndof)
    ydot_at_tilde = [0] * (ndof)

    ydot = rhs(y, ydot)
    # Note: In python range means:
    # range (first element, upto but not including last element)
    for i in range(0, ndof):
       y_tilde[i] = y[i] + dt * ydot[i]

    ydot_at_tilde = rhs(y_tilde, ydot_at_tilde)
    for i in range(0, ndof):
       y[i] = y[i] + dt/2 * (ydot[i] + ydot_at_tilde[i])

    t = t + dt
    # Note: This lists the output arguments:
    return y, t;

# Initial condition
y = [1, 1]
t = 0

dt     = 0.01
nsteps = 100
ndof = 2

istep = 1
while istep <= nsteps:
    # Note: This is how you get the output arguments:
    y, t = heun (ndof, dt, y, t)
    istep = istep + 1

print t, y[0], y[1]
```

Comment: What's the point of `rhs` if you can simply do `ydot[:1] = y[:1]`?

Comment: Just a test.  In the future ydot could be a more complicated function of y.

Comment: For example, for the person I am helping the rhs of the ODE system would be the Lotka-Volterra predator-prey equations.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

```
import numpy

def heun(ndof, dt, y, t):
    ydot = numpy.zeros(ndof)
    y_tilde = numpy.zeros(ndof)
    ydot_at_tilde = numpy.zeros(ndof)

    # Replacing first two elements does not need a function `rhs()`
    ydot[:1] = y[:1]
    # Vectorized operation, numpy does this loop for you at C speeds
    y_tilde = y + dt * ydot

    ydot_at_tilde[:1] = y_tilde[:1]
    y = y + dt/2 * (ydot + ydot_at_tilde)

    t = t + dt

    return y, t

y = numpy.ones(2)
t = 0

dt = 0.01
nsteps = 100
ndof = 2

for istep in range(nsteps):
    y, t = heun(ndof, dt, y, t)

print(t, y[0], y[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

`return;` From this it is clear that you're modifying the ydot but not returning anything.

And in `rhs(y, ydot)` you're passing in ydot without first specifying what it should be. Hence declare a function variable ydot first with `ydot = []` and hold the result in ydot as `ydot = rhs(y,ydot)` in `heun` and use

```
ydot.append(y[0])
ydot.append(y[1])
```

in 'rhs'.

`return ydot` in `rhs` and `return y` in `heun`.

Fix all the not defined errors in a similar manner.

Comment: OK I added these initializations at the beginning of subroutine:

Comment: @Old_But_Curious which subroutine? I've marked the function names so you'll know where to alter what. What output are you getting now?

Comment: I added these intializations in subroutine heun and am getting warm:      
    ydot          = [0] * (imax + 1)
    y_tilde       = [0] * (imax + 1)
    ydot_at_tilde = [0] * (imax + 1)                                                                   
  Unfortunately the answer for t, y[0], y[1] at the end of 100 steps is: 0 2.71823686256 1.  For some reason t and y[1] are not incrementing.  Note that my initial condition was wrong in the original code.  It should have been y = [1, 1].